# passing function to kartik file uploader in yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

I have a form which has an input field and kartik file uploader using ajax. Am trying to pass a function to take the id of the form field and pass it to the uploader but I always get an error

CODE:

The view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'case_description',['id'=>'case_description'])->textArea();?>
<?php   echo $form->field($evidence, 'path')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                    'options' => ['accept' => '*','multiple' => true,'name'=>'images'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                 'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                    'showPreview' => true,
                    'showCaption' => true,
                    'showRemove' => true,
                    'showUpload' => true,

                    'browseLabel' =>  'Insert Evidence',
                   'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['cases/upload']),
                   'maxFileCount' => 10,
                 'uploadExtraData' => function() {  // callback example
     return   $('#case_description').val() ;
 }],    

]
);?>
```

In the controller action upload I test if the value of id(case_description) is passed but I always get null with an error of unexpected[] at the line containing uploadextra data in the uploader

Controller code

```
public function actionUpload(){
var_dump($_POST);
}
```